# VTK Unresolved External Symbol vtkIneractionStyle_AutoInit_Construct

Tags: c++, vtk, opencascade

guys! I followed the lessons by Quaoar's Workshop on Youtube, downloaded the source code of vtk (version: 9.2.6), and compiled it successfully. However, when I included the following line in my `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <vtkAutoInit.h> 
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkIneractionStyle)
```

I ran into a link error. The output is:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl vtkIneractionStyle_AutoInit_Construct(void)" (?vtkIneractionStyle_AutoInit_Construct@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::vtkIneractionStyle_ModuleInit::vtkIneractionStyle_ModuleInit(void)" (??0vtkIneractionStyle_ModuleInit@?A0x14dbff40@@QEAA@XZ)
1>C:\Programs\HelloOCCT\x64\Debug\HelloOCCT.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Then I typed `vtkIneractionStyle_AutoInit_Construct` in `Far.exe`, but I can't find any related libaries in the `VTK\lib` directory. Note that the project is constructed from an empty project and there is only main.cpp in my project(no `CMakeLists.txt`). I already set `Additional include Directories` for C++, `Additional Library Directories` and `Additional Dependencies` for Linker and system `PATH`. Here is `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox.hxx>
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>

VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkIneractionStyle)

int main()
{
    BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox mkBox(1., 2., 3.);
    const TopoDS_Shape& shape = mkBox.Shape();
    vtkNew<vtkRenderWindow> renwin;
    vtkNew<vtkRenderer> ren;
    renwin->AddRenderer(ren);
    vtkNew<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera> istyle;
    vtkNew<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> iren;
    iren->SetRenderWindow(renwin);
    iren->SetInteractorStyle(istyle);
    renwin->Render();
    iren->Start();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to solve the problem?